# Notifying child classes that different value assigned to property in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, observable, behaviorsubject

I would like to notify my derived classes that base field has been set to a different value, in Angular.

So I have:

```
export abstract class BaseComponent<TSetting>
{
    setting: TSetting;

    async load() {
        this.setting = await _service.load(id);
    }

    async save() {
        await _service.save(this.setting);
        this.setting = await _service.load(id);
    }

    ... formGroup stuff
}

class ChildComponent : BaseComponent<Sett> 
{
    // want to fire method when something 
    // is assigned to this.setting
    async doWhenSettingsLoaded() { }
}
```

I thought of doing:

```
export abstract class BaseComponent<TSetting>
{
    setting: TSetting;
    settingChanged$ = new BehaviorSubject<TSetting>(null);

    async load() {
        this.setting = await _service.load(id);
        settingChanged$.next(this.setting):
    }

    async save() {
        await _service.save(this.readForm());
        await load();
    }
}
```

And then subscribing to `settingChanged$` in derived classes. Alternatively, I can override `load()` in a child class also, but I feel this is not a common practice in Angular.

But then it also occurred I could perhaps get rid of the `setting` property altogether and use a getter:

```
export abstract class BaseComponent<TSetting>
{
    setting$ = new BehaviorSubject<TSetting>(null);
    get setting() { return settingChanged$.getValue(); }

    async load() {
        settingChanged$.next(await _service.load(id)):
    }

    async save() {
        await _service.save(this.readForm());
        await load();
    }
}
```

Which effectively makes `setting` immutable along.

Are there any issues with using the latter approach?

Comment: Why expose `setting` synchronously at all?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: it's an existing piece of code with a bunch of derived classes, so it is used all around those components to affect their UI state (because Angular acts on changes to plain properties anyway, when updating templates). Now I just need to add a new component which should do an action after loading.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using an abstract method will do the trick ?

In base component:

```
export abstract class BaseComponent<TSetting>
{
    setting: TSetting;

    async load() {
        this.setting = await _service.load(id);
        this.doWhenSettingsLoaded();
    }

   abstract doWhenSettingsLoaded();
}
```

In child component:

```
class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent<Sett> 
{
    // called by parent component
    doWhenSettingsLoaded() {

     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the OOP approach, yes. I don't see it used that much in Angular code for some reason.

Comment: it has nothing to do with Angular, its pure javascript code and OOP approch as you said